# Compare DateTime in a generic list

Tags: c#, generic-list

I'm trying to query a generic list using code below.

```
    ArticleStartDate = Convert.ToDateTime("2013-05-07 09:00:00.450");
    var queryable = context.GetQueryable<FeaturedArticleResultItem>()
    queryable = queryable.Where(t => t.StartDisplay > ArticleStartDate).OrderBy(t => t.StartDisplay);
```

I'd like to get results which has a 'StartDisplay' date time later then 9:00am 7th of May, and my query returns list of items later then the day (7th, which is good), however, I've also got the items in the list like 8:30am 7th of May. It looks like it compares the date ok, but not the time...

Hope the above make sense.

Just a bit more info, I just found that **t.StartDisplay** looks like this {7/05/2013 1:31:00 a.m.}. Does it matter when comparing the time?

Comment: I would double check a few things 1) is `ArticleStartDate` parsing correctly before you go in to the query (Check the date and time, You may be getting July 5th or the time may not be parsing or else something weird), 2) are you sure the incorrect result you are looking at is on the 7th at 8:30 and not the 8th at 8:30 (or perhaps you are looking at the wrong month or year)

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure the Datetime ArticleStartDate is parsed correct, and it's 7th of may 2013. not sure what went wrong...

Comment: is your server and client running on the same timezone? Can you place a profiler on the server to check what is the datetime that is passed to it?